# Как сделать один gulp file на несколько сайтов?

Tags: javascript, gulp

Есть много отдельных почти уникальных страниц сайта со своей файловой структурой и сборкой, но в них используется шаблон шапки, который лежит в отдельной папке и импортируется в каждую страницу.

Вот шаблон шапки поменялся и приходится запускать каждую сборку в ручную.

Подскажите, как организовать сборку всего одновременно? Но не работая над отдельной страницей, а по необходимости. Чтобы не плодить столько сборщиков.

```
Корневая папка/
--Templates
--AllPages/ тут много папок page
  --Page/
    --build/
      --index.html
      --css
      --js
    --src/
      --index.html
      --sass
      --js
```

Answer (score 0):

Можно использовать require где записать нужные пути для определенных сборок, и создать универсальный шаблон который будет анализировать "шапку" и распихивать пути по нужным задачам